# Ionic v1 app crashing when opening url’s

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, runtime

My Ionic v1 app crashes on Android devices (6.0.1, 5.1.1 and 4.4.2) when I attempt to click on a simple link like

```
a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google
```

The same link works fine on IOS devices (9.3, 10). I've tried `_parent`, `_self`, `_system` and `_blank` targets but all have the same result.

My developer has been too busy to help resolve the bug so I'm trying to see if it is something I can fix.

I took a logcat on the Android device and have shared the results below when the error occurs. However, I don't know what to do next. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

> 02-19 18:14:52.765 12520 12609 E PushPlugin: execute: Got JSON
>   Exception No value for senderID 02-19 18:14:53.735  1476  3033 E
>   Watchdog: !@Sync 3699 [02-19 18:14:53.748] 02-19 18:14:54.895 12520
>   12520 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-19 18:14:54.895 12520
>   12520 E AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   com.completevirtualsolutions.eKnowtify, PID: 12520 02-19 18:14:54.895
>   12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
>   02-19 18:14:54.895 12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2558) 02-19
>   18:14:54.895 12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2001) 02-19
>   18:14:54.895 12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987) 02-19
>   18:14:54.895 12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1961) 02-19
>   18:14:54.895 12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser$5.run(InAppBrowser.java:606)
>   02-19 18:14:54.895 12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6035) 02-19
>   18:14:54.895 12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser.showWebPage(InAppBrowser.java:779)
>   02-19 18:14:54.895 12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser$1.run(InAppBrowser.java:198)
>   02-19 18:14:54.895 12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 02-19 18:14:54.895
>   12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 02-19 18:14:54.895
>   12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 02-19 18:14:54.895 12520 12520
>   E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 02-19
>   18:14:54.895 12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 02-19 18:14:54.895
>   12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>   02-19 18:14:54.895 12520 12520 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 02-19
>   18:14:54.975  1476 12638 E android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
>   02-19 18:14:54.975  1476 12638 E android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level =
>   0x4f4c 02-19 18:14:54.975  1476 12638 E android.os.Debug:
>   sys.mobilecare.preload = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reinstall the **cordova-plugin-inappbrowser** plugin:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

In HTML i prefer:

```
<a class="item item-icon-left" href="javascript:window.open('https://www.facebook.com/pimpolhoprodutos', '_system');">
    <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i>
    Facebook
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Dreadnought. Removing and installing the new inappbrowser plugin did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help you with my answer below:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank'); return false;">Google</a>
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't resolve the issue Andrei. I had to remove and install the new inappbrowser plugin.